# Number of times to roll a die

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

The program rolls a certain amount of dice with a certain about of sides a certain amount of times, all of which are set by the user. I have been debugging and troubleshooting why it is not working for 4 days now and cannot figure it out.

I know its a problem is with generating the random number a certain amount of times (per each die thrown around line 38), but when the code compiles the way it is below all the array values that have increased are multiples of the number of dice that are to be used (inputed by user) and i can't figure out a way to make the program loop the random number generator for all the number of dice thrown while still incrementing the array values.

```
 package DiceRolls_2;

import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.lang.Math; 

public class DiceRolls_2
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
int numRolls;   //number of rolls
int outcome;    //index value to be +1'd
int numDice;    //number of dice to be thrown
int numSides;   //number of sides per die
int arraySize;  //size of array (dependant on number of sides)
int minRoll;    //minimum roll value (number of die (each one rolls 1)
int maxRoll;    //maximum roll value (number of sides (each side increments +1 to total roll possibility))

/* prompt user for number of rolls */ 
System.out.print("How many rolls? "); 
numRolls = input.nextInt(); //sets number of rolls

System.out.print("How many dice to roll? ");
numDice = input.nextInt();

System.out.print("How many sides per die? ");
numSides = input.nextInt(); 

maxRoll = numSides*numDice; //max roll is equal to num sides because the highest value number is the latest (highest) side number
minRoll = numDice;          //minimum roll is equal to number of dice since each dice has a 1 value
arraySize = maxRoll + 1;    //size of array depends on the maximum roll value + 1 for positioning of index values
int[] outcomes = new int[arraySize]; 


/* roll dice and add to outcomes */ 
for (int roll = 0; roll <= numRolls; roll++) 
{
    int numberRolled = (int) (numSides * Math.random() + 1);
    outcome = numberRolled;
    outcomes[outcome] += 1; 
}



/* show counts of outcomes */ 
for (int i = minRoll; i <= maxRoll; i++)            //3 is the minimum number (1) all number of dice can roll (dependant on number of dice are being rolled)
{                                                   //18 is maximum number all 3 dice (6 per die) can roll (dependant on number of dice are being rolled) 
    System.out.println(i + ": " + outcomes[i]);     //prints all array values with number of occurances
}
input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need a nested loop.  Inside the loop for `numRolls`, add a loop for `numDice`.

Answer (score 1):

The number of outcomes is the number of dices multiplied by the number of roles (not the number of sides). I simplified your code a little bit, you only need one loop to store and print (for example), and your variable declarations can be moved to where they are needed. Like,

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("How many rolls? ");
int numRolls = input.nextInt();

System.out.print("How many dice to roll? ");
int numDice = input.nextInt();

System.out.print("How many sides per die? ");
int numSides = input.nextInt();
int[] outcomes = new int[numDice * numRolls];

for (int roll = 0; roll < outcomes.length; roll++) {
    outcomes[roll] = 1 + (int) (numSides * Math.random());
    System.out.printf("%d: %d%n", roll, outcomes[roll]);
}
```